# Convert string to Byte[] Java

Tags: java

I have a string which represents an application (converted in bytes and then encoded in base64 -- if you ask yourself why, it is because i am transferring an application from a server to the client, in the hope of rebuilding it when transferred).

How would I get a Byte array back from this string?

Comment: `string.getBytes()` ?

Answer (score 3):

String class has what you need (in java, a String is a class)

```
   "this is a string".getBytes();
```

also take a look at this for base64 decoding of the String

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

java from 8 and beyond also has a base64 class built-in

```
java.util.Base64
```

Comment: Don't forget about charset. In any OS u can get different results